# Masked Array: How to change symbol representing masked values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to change the symbol representing masked values in printed masked array. What I get is:

```
>>> print ma.array([[1, 0,0,1],[1,0,1,0]],mask=[[0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1]])
[[1 0 0 --]
 [-- -- 1 --]]
```

I would prefer:

```
[[1 0 0 -]
 [- - 1 -]]
```

I've tried to set `numpy.ma.masked_print_option`, but it does not work:

```
>>> numpy.ma.masked_print_options = '-'
>>> print ma.array([[1, 0,0,1],[1,0,1,0]],mask=[[0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1]])
[[1 0 0 --]
 [-- -- 1 --]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You were close!

```
In [4]: np.ma.masked_print_option.set_display("-")

In [5]: np.ma.array([[1, 0,0,1],[1,0,1,0]],mask=[[0,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1]])
Out[5]:
masked_array(data =
 [[1 0 0 -]
 [- - 1 -]],
             mask =
 [[False False False  True]
 [ True  True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```